# Close/Tight Alliance?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, antonyms

I have a question about the antonym of the adjective "***loose***" in this context:

> The two countries formed a loose alliance.

For a "***loose*** *alliance*", would a "***close*** *alliance*" or a "**tight** *alliance*" work as a good opposite?

Comment: A **close-knit** alliance is common as well.

Answer (score 2):

Both would be quite acceptable.

ngrams shows that "close alliance" [is much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=close+alliance%2C+tight+alliance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclose%20alliance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctight%20alliance%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Then, for a "***loose relationship***", would a "***close*** relationship" or a "***tight*** relationship" work as a good opposite as well?